# Generate an SWC file in Flash AS3 that contains ASDOCS

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swc

I can create SWC files. I can create ASDOCs.

Is there any way of combining this in Flash IDE or FlashDevelop? I would like the ASDOCs to "live" in the SWC.

Answer (score 0):

Basically an .swc file is a compressed archive similar to .zip.

Hence you should be able to:

1. Generate your ASDoc
2. Archive them + your source code into your .swc

Have a look at [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) which can simply be run from the command line.

Cheers

Comment: But would this enable codehinting and autocomplete in FlashDevelop?